# Bootstrap 4.6 container's children only using half page height

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I  am trying to work with bootstrap 4.6 and I am using its container layout. It only takes the height of its children so i gave it min-vh-100 attribute and gave its child component height: 100%. At this point the container has 100% height of the page but the child component only has 50% height but when I give the child component a height of 100 vh it works and it stretches fully but i want the height 100% to work because inside the child component I have 2 elements one is nav bar of fixed height and I want the other component to occupy the rest of the space.

The below screenshot shows how the container has total page height

[Parent element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIpad.jpg)

This pictures shows the child taking only half of parents height

[Child Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpJQf.jpg)

I gave height as 100% for both the child and its successive child too.

```
.inner-canvas {
 height: 100%;
 align-self: flex-end;
}

.in-can {
 height: 100%;
}
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong! Thanks in advance.

My html code

```
<div className="container-fluid main-canvas p-0 min-vh-100">
      <div className="inner-canvas">
        <Navbar/>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your Bootstrap HTML code?

Comment: @RichDeBourke ` <div className="container-fluid main-canvas p-0 min-vh-100">`
      <div className="inner-canvas">
        <Navbar/>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div> `

Comment: Hi Harshak – I see you added a small piece of your code, but it’s not enough to reproduce the problem. It’s best to include enough of your code that runs in a browser (not the code from your server with the brackets like {props.children}) to [reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Stackoverflow has a the ability to include runnable code sections in your question that you can [check out](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).